# Multiple address rows with state list based on country

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have multiple address rows with a state and country combo box. I limit the state list based on the country. It looks like

[image: Imgur]

However, when I change the value of the state and this detail row loses focus, it saves and clears the value of the other state like

[image: Imgur]

I have an event on the state field to set the list when it gets focus.

```
Private Sub cboState_GotFocus()
    MsgBox ("Country: " & Me.cboCountry.value)
    If Nz(Me.cboCountry, 0) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a country first"
        Me.cboCountry.SetFocus
    Else
        If Nz(Me.cboCountry.value, 0) = 0 Then
            Me.cboState.RowSource = ""
        Else
            Me.cboState.RowSource = "SELECT id, stateCode, stateName FROM state where country_id = " & Me.cboCountry.value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried setting 'Limit to List' to No, but it gave an error

[image: Imgur]

I tried setting Column Widths to `0.001";0.3938";1.1806"`, but then it displayed the id field instead of the state code. Here are the current values

```
Column Count  3
Column Widths 0";0.3938";1.1806"
Row Source    SELECT id, stateCode, stateName FROM state where country_id = [country_id]
Bound Column  1
Limit to List Yes
```

How can I have multiple state combo boxes, each with a different restricted list based on the country?

Comment: Would changing the order of the fields in the Row Source query make this easier? `SELECT stateCode, stateName, id FROM ...`

Comment: This forum comment says 'No'. http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/different-rowsource-combo-box-datasheet-each-row-t3096710.html

Comment: @HansUp Wow that's a great idea. I tried setting `Column Widths: 0.3938";1.1806";0"`, `Bound to Column: 3`, and `Limit to List: No`, but it still gave the error in the dialog above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Access combobox whose `LimitToList` property is set to `Yes` can only show values returned by the `RowSource` property, even if the `ControlSource` is set to another value.

The workaround is to put a `textbox` on top of the `combobox` (but not covering the arrow) and show the text value in the `textbox`, using `=Dlookup("textvalue","tbl","Id = " & numericvalue)` in the `ControlSource` property. That way you can show a value that is not in the list.

Comment: Clever! I tried that with `Private Sub cboState_Change() \n
    txtStateCode.value = cboState.Column(1)` but when I changed one state combo box, BOTH text fields were updated!

Comment: Don't look for the value in the combobox, it isn't there. Use a `Dlookup` in the textbox to get the value directly from the table.

Comment: That still didn't work. `Private Sub cboState_Change() \n
    Me.txtStateCode.value = DLookup("stateCode", "state", "id =" & Me.cboState.value)`. It still changes BOTH text fields in every row.

Comment: I was able to do it by setting the text box `ControlSource ="=IIf(IsNull([state_id]),\"\",DLookUp(\"stateCode\",\"state\",\"id =\" & nz([cboState],[state_id])))"`, keeping the combo box bound to state_id, and with judicial and prudent use of onClick and onUpdate events for the state list and country list, but NOT `cboState_Change`.